# Alternative for sqlRestrictions in hibernate 6.2.7

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hibernate 6.2.7 removed the support of sqlRestrictions. I want to use SIMILAR TO operator of postgresql. How can achieve this with hibernate 6.2.7?

Thanks in advance!